# Latest (2.14.1) Log4J2 async appender causes Java process to hang

Tags: log4j2, asyncappender

I have a very basic (almost textbook) Log4J2 sample, using latest (2.14.1):

`log4j2.xml` (taken from the [official appender doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Program, `TestLog.java`:

```
public class TestLog {
    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger l = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(TestLog.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        l.error("Boo");
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2-not-shutting-down</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I run this, I do get the expected ERROR log line in `logs/app.log`; however the Java process hangs (does not shut down after `main()` completes). A thread dump shows (in addition to Java's native threads) a non-daemon async-appender thread that remains `WAITING` (most probably the cause for the hang).

```
"Log4j2-AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher-1-Async" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=17.04s tid=0x000001bd5bc98000 nid=0x7324 waiting on condition  [0x0000006962bff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@12/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007110c2618> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@12/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@12/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(java.base@12/ArrayBlockingQueue.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.dispatchAll(AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:70)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.run(AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher.java:62)
```

- Removing the `Async` appender (and directly appending to `MyFile`) causes the program to shut down properly.
- Adding a `shutdownTimeout` to the `Async` appender definition has no effect. (Anyways the only log line already gets written to the file properly, so it could not possibly be a queueing issue.)
- Switching `log4j-core` to a lower version (e.g. `2.9.1`) also resolves the hang.

Is this the expected behavior, or a bug? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be [already reported and fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3102).

Anyways 2.14.1 is no longer viable (due to the infamous [CVE-2021-44228 RCE vulnerability](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3230)), and given the [several vulnerabilities discovered afterwards](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) it is now recommended to upgrade to 2.17.0 or above - where the originally stated LOG4J2-3102 is also fixed.